# Scroll to element on orientationchange with if conditions jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientation-changes

I want to my page to scroll to exact line (an element) **only** when a user changes its device orientation from `landscape` to `portrait` (this is the first condition) and **only** if `modal` is closed (not open, this is the second condition).

I have a difficulty to write this in code with jQuery, this is what I'm tried so far:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) && $(".modal").hide();  {
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#exact-line').offset().top);
  }  
});
```

1. How to properly set `if` for a `modal` to define that it wasn't present present on page? (I can't use `display: none` in this case);
2. How to properly set up an `eventListner` for orientation change and make my function to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".modal").hide()
```

is the code to hide the modal, not to check if it is closed. You need to use `$(".modal").is(':visible');` in your condition.

If I understand you correctly though, you want to check not only that the modal is not visible right now, but never was visible since page load. To accomplish that I would define a boolean variable, and set it to false as soon as the modal gets opened. I assume you are using Bootstap modals, `'shown.bs.modal'` is the event that fires when a modal gets opened: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events

```
// variable to store the visibility
var modal_was_not_visible = true;

// listener for modal open
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // set variable to false since modal is displayed
  modal_was_not_visible = false;
})

// use variable for your condition
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches && modal_was_not_visible)  {
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#exact-line').offset().top);
  }  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, no, just simple check if modal is open/close is enough (ps, this is simple jquery modal, not boot strap modal). Before posting this question I also tried this function only with one if - (orientationchange), but it didn’t work on rotate event (iOS) and I wonder maybe something wrong with eventListener-thing to accomplish my goal?